Access Vue3 (composition API) component's states from dusk test
(Laravel, Vue3, Inertia)
Maybe it's seems a very simply question, but it is not that.
There is Vue component, which has a child component, which has a computed state.
ParentComponent template:
<ChildComponent dusk="child-component"/>

in the ChildComponent:
const childState = computed(() => ...

During the dusk test, I need value of childState from ChildComponent.
Under Vue3, the $browser->assertVue() and some similar ...Vue method does not works.
I tried other lot of approach (etc. some script), but they did not works too.
One of them (maybe this is the closest to the solution):
$childState = $browser->script([
    "return document.querySelector('[dusk=\"child-component\"]').__vueParentComponent.childState",
]);

Anybody has an idea?
Thanks

what do you want. do you want te get an element and its contents or do you want to assert something what needs to happen in the dusk
